# Magento Security Patch SUPEE-5994, how do I verify installation?

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches

After installing security patch SUPEE-5994, how do I verify whether patch is installed successfully. Will the test at http://magento.com/security-patch find out if the patch is installed?

Comment: That magento link/test might be broken.  It throws errors about not being able to find any of my public sites, but I can get to them fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you applied the patch via SSH you will see modified files if your files are under version control. Furthermore you should see a new entry in `app/etc/applied.patches.list`. The entry will mention SUPEE-599**8**, but it's done by SUPEE-5994. The bugtester mentioned above was created for the SUPEE-5344 patch so this will not check your latest patch (SUPEE-5994).

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have version control in place, you have to check manually.

Entering `find . -mtime 0` in your Magento root folder immediately after running the shell patch will give you a list of changed files to compare against the file changes in `app/etc/applied.patches.list`.

It's highly necessary on this one to check for file creation because despite the reported file changes in `applied.patches.list`, 5994 can fail to create `app/code/core/Mage/Install/Controller/Router/Install.php` because it trips up on there not being a `Router` directory in `app/code/core/Mage/Install/Controller/`.

And as noted, the Magento Shoplift check page only looks for the 5344 vulnerability.

Answer (score 5):

The test at magento.com/security-patch only checks for patch 5344. You can check for proper installation of all recent patches at https://www.magereport.com. This will check correct behavior, not the status in app/etc/applied.patches.list. If you forget to clear a cache, a behavior based test will give a more accurate report.

*Disclaimer: site made by me*